# How do i get a callback from another application

Tags: swift, callback, deep-linking

Much like facebook login SDK i want to open a third party application and then when i'm done with my task in that application go back to the previous application. How is this done? I can't find information about it as most people say that i should just URL-scheme my way back, but the problem is that the app that i will open from is unknown and you can't add URL-schemes in runtime.

But as i have seen it in both Facebook SDK and other places where you for instance login through some homepage, i know it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's harder to answer your question without more context but You can use Apple's App Extension for it.

Here is the link for same

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/

Comment: If i understood it correctly it basically says you never open the app, you just request some data from it? That wont work, because you . have to open the app, connect a bluetooth device and execute some action on it and then once done (a couple of tries) you can go back

Comment: No you can open portion of another app inside your application